# Lex program output is not coming

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

```
%{
    int count=0;
%}
%%
    [/][/][a-zA-Z0-9]* {count++;}
%%
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    yylex();
    printf("lines: %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

I am executing this code and am entering multiple lines but no output is being generated and as I press Ctrl+C, the program terminates. please help!!

Comment: That's what Ctrl+C does: it immediately kills the program. If you want to tell the program that there is no more input, use Ctrl+D (on Linux/Mac) or Ctrl+Z (on Windows).

Comment: Also, you **must not** indent your flex rules. A flex pattern must start at the left margin; the action must be on the same line, with at least one space between them. As written, your scanner cannot be compiled, so perhaps your copy and paste is not accurate.

Comment: @rici with Ctrl+Z, I am getting "input in flex scanner failed" and I have just applied the indentation as stack overflow was not allowing to post the question without proper format of code.. with the same code all my friends were getting the output. nothing is getting printed....for other programs it is working fine so I guess it is not taking multi-line input.. so if you could pls help on that

Comment: How are you compiling and running that program?

Comment: You should change `printf("lines: %d",count);` to `printf("lines: %d\n",count);`. Some IDEs don't print the last line if it does not end with a newline character. Assuming you fix the format of the rule, there is nothing which prevents that program from working, unless there is some problem with the way you compiled it.

Comment: @rici in cmd, I am writing flex filename.l then lex gcc.yy.c and then a.exe, after that it takes the input but when I press Ctrl+C after entering one or two lines, nothing is displayed. These are the exact lines from cmd                         
 C:\Users\hp\Desktop\flex programs>flex print.l

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\flex programs>gcc lex.yy.c

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\flex programs>a.exe
//fekfjeke
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\flex programs>

Comment: As I said at the beginning, if you press Ctrl-C, you're telling `cmd` to kill off the running process. So it will just die. It won't execute the `printf`. You need to use Ctrl-Z.

Comment: @rici with Ctrl+Z, I am getting "input in flex scanner failed" or is there any other online lex tool available

Comment: That error message occurs if the scanner gets an I/O error when trying to read its input. I'm not a Windows programmer, but I don't see any reason why it would signal an I/O error on console read. (And what do you mean by "online lex tool"? You're not using any online tools, right?)

Comment: Anyway, I can 't reproduce the problem on the machine I have available (which does not run Windows). Sorry.